# Galaxy S4: "Application cannot be installed in the default install location"

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, storage

I had uninstalled some of my apps but now I can't install them again. Play Store gives me "Application cannot be installed in the default install location" error when the download is complete.

I guess it's a common problem but none of the solutions worked!

I don't even have an SD card! How the hell am I going to solve this problem?

Comment: What are "the solutions" you've tried? Have you checked out [similar issues on this site](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Application+cannot+be+installed+in+the+default+install+location) – and if so, which?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of [Play Store 4.9.13 insufficient storage error and icon issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79544/play-store-4-9-13-insufficient-storage-error-and-icon-issues)

But my rep can't comment yet, so I'll repeat my answer:

The correct answer to this problem, and I always see wrong explanations, is that you have a duplicate **/data/app-lib** folder for the app or apps that are giving you that error.

To fix: Using adb, terminal, or root explorer:

compare **/data/app** to **/data/app-lib**

you will see, for example:

1. **/data/app/example-app-1.apk**
2. **/data/app-lib/example-app-1**
3. **/data/app-lib/example-app-2**

*OR*

1. **/data/app/example-app-2.apk**
2. **/data/app-lib/example-app-1**
3. **/data/app-lib/example-app-2**

So for 1st example remove directory: **/data/app-lib/example-app-2**

and for 2nd example remove directory: **/data/app-lib/example-app-1**

Then your app will install just fine!

**ALWAYS REMEMBER TO KEEP THE SAME NUMBERS,**

**IF THE APK IS 1 REMOVE 2... IF THE APK IS 2 REMOVE 1!**

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling unused apps and downloading the new one. Also try using task killer (if you have it) and killed running apps. I hope this helps with your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Well, It might be that you have a lot of stuff that filled up your storage. Deleting a little might not help. Try deleting some stuff like, videos you made from camera, apps you never used, or other. If your not comfortable with it, then you have to try get an SD card. It can be your only solution.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error, and after clearing up some memory I was able to install apps again. I guess it's a feature: if your available memory is less than 500 MB, it wont install anything.